# Subtraction giving null in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a table temp(id int,name text) and another table temp2(id int,times int). temp stores (1,'a'),(2,'b') and (3,'c'). temp2 stores (1,1) and (2,2). I want to find the difference between the id of a character and the number of times it comes. Because 'c' doesn't appear in the temp2 column, its times is null. Further, please note that I can't edit the given tables in any way. Here's what I did:-

```
SELECT name, temp.id,
CASE WHEN times=null THEN temp.id
    ELSE temp.id-times
END
FROM temp LEFT OUTER JOIN temp2
ON (temp.id=temp2.id);
```

But, the problem with this is that it still gives me this output:-

```
 name | id | case 
------+----+------
 a    |  1 |    0
 b    |  2 |    0
 c    |  3 |     

(3 rows)
```

(Note that case is null for c). Please help me solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT name, temp.id,
       temp.id - COALESCE(times, 0)
FROM temp LEFT OUTER JOIN
     temp2
     ON temp.id = temp2.id;
```

Your specific problem is the comparison `= NULL`.  The correct method would be `IS NULL`.  Nothing can be "equal" to `NULL` in SQL, so that never returns `TRUE`.

However, `COALESCE()` is a simpler way to express the logic.